# How to check the color of a certain part of an image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I am making a simple game that uses "AI players" (they aren't *really* AI players). I need to find out if a certain part of the "map" I am using has certain colors, so I can make the "AI players" do certain things. Is it possible to do this?

I don't know if this will help, but a game called "Warcraft 3" uses a very similar thing to determine certain things, such as movement. If you know of this game, it should be a lot easier to understand this question.

I think this may be possible if I put the image into a custom `NSView` subclass, but I have not yet learned how to check colors there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **NSBitmapImageRep** from the NSImage and use **colorAtX:y:** to get the color.

Check:
[NSBitmapImageRep Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be not to bother checking the colors of the actual image (which can be an expensive operation if you're checking a lot of individual pixels), but to indicate in your map's data structure the characteristics you want to have, and then take *both* the color and player behavior from that.

In pseudocode:

```
// Draw Map
foreach currSquare in listOfSquares:
    if map[currSquare].hasPropertyX():
        drawSquare(currSquare, blue)
    else if map[currSquare].hasPropertyY():
        drawSquare(currSquare, red)

// Move pieces
foreach currPlayer in listOfPlayers:
    squareIAmStandingOn = currPlayer.square
    if map[squareIAmStandingOn].hasPropertyX():
        currPlayer.takeActionX()
    else if map[squareIAmStandingOn].hasPropertyY():
        currPlayer.takeActionY()
```

Comment: That obviously is not Objective-C, so how do I add that code to my Xcode project?

Comment: @Justin: as I said, that's pseudocode. I don't know what your map data structure or your drawing code or your player classes look like. My point was simply that you don't have to draw the picture of the map and then extract the information you need from the picture. Whatever information you use to draw the picture is also accessible for other decision making, and it will be a lot easier to access it at that level.